# Operator OR not working

Tags: python-3.x

Okay, so maybe this topic has already been answered in another Stock Exchange topic directly or indirectly, but I couldn't find one, so if you do find an appropriate post with answer that you think works, please link me too that post.

Below is my code:

```
while True:
    example=input('Enter something')
    if example=='Hi' or 'Bye':
        print('Yay!')
    else:
        print('Something else.')
```

When `example` does not result in the `if` statement resulting in `True`, (`if` I don't enter 'Hi' `or` 'Bye' into `example`), it fails to `print` the `else` statement and it instead, it will `print` the return greeting in my `if` statement. Why is this? Is this called short circuiting? And most importantly, how do I fix this? I'd like to know this because otherwise I would have to make a separate `elif` statement, which takes a lot more code.

Please try to explain your answers in using basic terminology. By the way, I'm using Python 3.4.3.

Comment: That's not the correct way of using `or`

Answer (score 2):

To add onto what was said above, you can also do:

```
if example in ['Hi', 'Bye']:
```

This is a bit more practical if the list is longer.

Comment: This is easier, more readable and arguably more pythonic. :)

Answer (score 1):

Use a tuple as they are quick and cheap to create for **small** lengths rather than a list:

```
if example in ('Hi', 'Bye'):
```

If you were going to do a large comparison *(larger than the example below!)* on a lot of different options then use a [`set`](http://www.python-course.eu/sets_frozensets.php) as a set can only contain unique entries and is better optimised for searching across:

```
if example in {'Hi', 'Bye', 'Hello', 'Goodbye', 'Adios', 'Bonjour'}:
```

**Off Topic** Often text inputs can contain unexpected cases. Adding `.lower()` and comparing to lowercase strings will avoid that...

```
if example.lower() in ('hi', 'bye'):
```